# Is there a way to declare a method "friendly" in Java?

Tags: java, methods, visibility

I know that attributes can be set `public`, `friendly` or `private` to specify its visibility.

Is there a way I can declare a `friendly` method? I want it to be accessible only from objects of classes of the same package.

Thanks you, a beginner here :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By not entering a visiblity modifier Java uses the package private scope

Check out the following [article](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Edit:  As mentioned in the comments, there is no way to mark a method as "friendly".  But for your needs, package-private will suffice.

Comment: Although, if we understand "friendly" in the C++ way, that's not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, true - but it seems this scope will suffice as Sergio only wants "it to be accessible only from objects of classes of the same package."

Answer (score 8):

Just don't specify the accessibility - that defaults to "package visible" or "default access". Unfortunately there's no way of doing this explicitly.

Note that `protected` access is not only related by inheritance, but also includes other types in the same package. (This has always seemed slightly odd to me, but never mind.)

See the [Java Language Specification section 6.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6) for details.

Comment: What's also unexpected for most, is that protected is less restrictive than package/default.

Comment: I've got just surprised by this. If I understand it, an inherited class(es) from a superclass has still access to its protected attributes even though the subclass is in a different package. It's actually make sense :)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible by just ommiting public/private in your method declaration. The method is implicitly public, but only accessible within the same package.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - do not put any modifier. Simply

`String myString;`

[Here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) you can see the semantics of each visibility modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Just say nothing, default is package visibility.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have public, protected, package and private visibility. Package visibility is also known as default since you specify it by leaving out the other keywords.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify any access modifier then the method will be "[package-private](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Access_Modifiers)" which sounds like it's what you want.