# Making a program friendly and making it use generics

Tags: java, class, generics, methods

I have a program that I wrote, MyStack.java and I am trying to turn it into MyStackGeneric.java. I am running into a few roadblocks.

I don't know how to:

- Make a CLASS friendly

or

- Convert the current methods that I have into generic methods.

I have found resources that suggest changing the methods I have into generics but the ones that are used in the examples have arguments while the methods in my program are not generic.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Iterator;

public abstract class MyStackGeneric extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    public void print() {
        Iterator s = this.iterator();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(s.next() + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public Object peek() {
        return this.get(getSize() - 1);
    }

    public Object pop() {
        Object o = this.get(getSize() - 1);
        this.remove(getSize() - 1);
        return o;
    }

    public void push(Integer o) {
        this.add(o);
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return this.isEmpty();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return this.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "stack: " + this.toString();
    }

    public void binaryOperator(char op) {
        Integer var1;
        Integer var2;
        boolean exist = true;
        if (op == '+') {
            try {
                var1 = (int) peek();
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: Need two operands");
                var1 = 0;
                exist = false;
            }
            if (exist)
                pop();
            try {
                var2 = (int) peek();
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: Need two operands");
                var2 = 0;
                exist = false;
            }
            if (exist)
                pop();
            var2 += var1;
            push(var2);
        }
        if (op == '-') {
            try {
                var1 = (int) peek();
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: Need two operands");
                var1 = 0;
                exist = false;
            }
            if (exist)
                pop();
            try {
                var2 = (int) peek();
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: Need two operands");
                var2 = 0;
                exist = false;
            }
            if (exist)
                pop();
            var2 -= var1;
            push(var2);
        }
    }

    public void readInput(Scanner s) {
        char c;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String[] strInput = s.next().split(" ");
            for (String s2 : strInput) {
                if (s2.matches("[+-]?\\d+")) {
                    push(Integer.parseInt(s2));
                } else if (s2.matches("[+-]")) {
                    c = s2.charAt(0);
                    binaryOperator(c);
                } else if (s2.matches("p")) {
                    print();
                } else if (s2.length() > 1) {
                    System.out.println("Exception: too long: " + s2);
                } else if (s2.length() == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Exception: Unknown Command " + s2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStack my = new MyStack();
        my.readInput(new Scanner(System.in));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard about friendly methods in Java before. As I found out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839365/is-there-a-way-to-declare-a-method-friendly-in-java):

> There is no way to mark a method as "friendly". But for your needs, package-private will suffice.

To generalise your class, you should replace all `Object`, `Integer` mentions with `T` and declare the class as follows:

```
public abstract class MyStackGeneric<T> { ... }
```

Note that `extends ArrayList<Integer>` makes the class dependent on the `Integer` implementation in the `ArrayList`:

```
public abstract  class MyStackGeneric<T> extends ArrayList<T> { ... }
```

By the way, you'd better not forget about raw types, don't use them:

```
Iterator<T> s = this.iterator();
         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing more "studying" on the concepts that you using in your source code:

1. You declared your class to be **abstract**. Why is that? There is absolutely **nothing** in that class indicating that it should/needs to be abstract.
2. Be careful about copy & paste: your main method in your new class ... is still using the *old* class name MyStack. So, you are not testing your new class, but the old one!
3. If you want **friendly** code; I suggest to make it **human reader friendly**. As honestly: this isn't exactly "great" code. One good starting point - "Clean Code" by Robert Martin. That book nicely explains to you how to write code that will make you friends (the code that you are writing as of now is more like: making people turn away, not wanting to look into it).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will be sure to check out that book.